# Calling an external API using a server

Tags: php, api

I'm PHP beginner and I'm using this API for one of my i Phone app project. I'm currently calling their API directly in the app.

```
https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD
```

But I'd like to know if it possible to use my own server to call this URL, incase if they shutdown the website I don't have to change my app code.

For an example I'd like to call my own server as below.

```
https://myserver.com/latest?base=USD
```

Is this achievable using PHP? If so, please guide me. I don't need the whole steps, just show me the way and I'll do my own research. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's good to be thinking about this in advance - well done. Yes, this is entirely possible. You'd need to write a PHP script that accessed that API [using `curl`](http://php.net/curl), and then output the results.

Comment: the data you are trying to access ( json ) is generated by `api.exchangeratesapi.io` - where they get the info from, if not from their own means, remains unknown. If you know the ultimate source then yes, you can use your own server to access that data directly in the manner you describe.

Comment: @RamRaider I believe OP wants to do `app --> OP's server --> api.exchangeratesapi.io` instead of `app --> api.exchangeratesapi.io`, which will allow them to swap out third-parties (if they go down, or start charging, or block OP, or any number of other issues) without updating the app itself.

Comment: @ceejayoz I think, in hindsight, you are most likely correct but I wasn't totally sure of the intention ~ it seemed a little ambiguous